# options_for_select on simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I'm probably using this incorrectly and I cant figure it out.

I am using an options_for_select on my simple_form. It renders fine with no errors, but the selected option does not save to the database. All other fields save no problems.

The select_tag is

```
<%= select_tag :experiment_type, options_for_select(['AOV', 'Conversion']), :prompt => "Select a Project Type" %>
```

Controller:

```
class ExperimentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_advertiser
    before_action :find_experiment, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]


    def index
        @experiments = Experiment.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show

    end

    def new
        @experiment = Experiment.new
        @advertisers = Advertiser.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }

    end

    def create
        @experiment = Experiment.new(experiment_params)
        @experiment.advertiser_id = params[:advertiser_id]   

        if @experiment.save
             redirect_to advertiser_path(@advertiser)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
            @projects = Project.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    end

    def update
        @experiment.advertiser_id = params[:id]     
        if @experiment.update(experiment_params)
            redirect_to experiment_path(@experiment)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @experiment.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

private

    def experiment_params
        params.require(:experiment).permit(:advertiser_id, :name, :experiment_type, :hypothesis, :priority, :status, :launch_date, 
            :description, :baseline_url, :test_url, :baseline_aov_60, :baseline_aov_30, :baseline_aov_mtd,
            :baseline_conversion_60, :baseline_conversion_30, :baseline_conversion_mtd)
    end

    def find_advertiser
        @advertiser = Advertiser.find(params[:advertiser_id])
    end

    def find_experiment
        @experiment = Experiment.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: Post your controller code

Comment: Ok, now is this problem for create? Update? Both? Show your model structure as well. Any errors in the console or log?

Comment: Can you post the error you getting? Did you set the data type correctly for `experiment_type` in the migrations?

Comment: A server log for the saving action would be useful.

Comment: @WesFoster - Problem is during the create action I think. The form partial is supposed to collect the info and send it to my database. All values are inserted, but the experiment_type is nil.

@Lahiru - My datatype for `experiment_type` is set as a string. Which I believe is correct. Looking in the MySQL db, its *varchar (255)*

@gen - I'll paste in my Rails Console. The Started POST has the correct value for `experiment_type` however the INSERT does not contain `experiment_type` at all.

Comment: "experiment_type"=>"AOV", "experiment"=>{"name"=>"Test", "priority"=>"7", "status"=>"Test", "launch_date(1i)"=>"2016", "launch_date(2i)"=>"6", "launch_date(3i)"=>"27", "description"=>"Test", "baseline_url"=>"http:www.baseline.com", "test_url"=>"http:www.test.com", "baseline_aov_60"=>"65", "baseline_aov_30"=>"65", "baseline_aov_mtd"=>"65", "baseline_conversion_60"=>"65", "baseline_conversion_30"=>"65", "baseline_conversion_mtd"=>"65", "hypothesis"=>"65"}, "commit"=>"Create Experiment", "advertiser_id"=>"5"}

Comment: (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO `experiments` (`name`, `hypothesis`, `priority`, `status`, `description`, `baseline_url`, `test_url`, `baseline_aov_60`, `baseline_aov_30`, `baseline_aov_mtd`, `baseline_conversion_60`, `baseline_conversion_30`, `baseline_conversion_mtd`, `launch_date`, `advertiser_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('Test', '65', 7, 'Test', 'Test', 'http:www.baseline.com', 'http:www.test.com', 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, '2016-06-27', 5, '2016-06-27 20:46:57', '2016-06-27 20:46:57')

Comment: @LeoLeGendre Please edit your original question, add all that information, then delete the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would need your full form layout to tell you for sure, but according to your experiment_params method, experiment_type field is a part of experiment. However, when you use just select_tag it is not connected to your main object. You need to use just `select`. Similar to this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :experiment do |f| %>
...
<%= f.select ... %>
...
<% end %>
```

or in the [simple_form format](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections):

```
<%= f.input :experiment_type, collection: ['AOV', 'Conversion'] %>
```

My guess is also based on your hash:

"experiment_type"=>"AOV", "experiment"=>{"name"=>"Test" ....

The experiment_type is outside of your "experiment".

Comment: Wahoo! That was it. So I guess I need to read up on select vs select_tag to understand the differences. Thanks a lot for your help man!

Comment: @LeoLeGendre: Welcome! Then I guess you can accept my answer.

Comment: @LeoLeGendre: Do you know how to accept answers? Under each answer to **your** question you have a blank check mark that you can click for accepting an answer.